# reactJs, nextJs, giving height of component to parent's parent

Tags: reactjs, next.js

- Parent

  - Child

    - Lowest Child

I'm trying to give my parent component the height of the lowest child component.  I have been able to give my parent component the height of the lowest child component but the value `navHeight` is scoped and I want to be give it to my HTML to style it:

`<Container className={styles.heroArticle} style={{ height: "calc(100vh - " + navHeight + "px)"}}>`
Results in error: navHeight is not defined

Not sure if I'm doing this the right way as I am new to react and nextjs

**Parent:**

```
export default function Home({ allPostsData }) {

      const pull_data = (data) => {
      const navHeight = data;
      console.log(navHeight); //Correctly outputs the right number
       }
 
      return (
    <div>
    <Layout home giveNavHeight={pull_data}>
    <Container className={styles.heroArticle} style={{ height: "calc(100vh - " + navHeight + "px)"}}> //Draws error (navHeight is undefined, I guess because navHeight is scoped)
```

**Child:**

```
   export default function Layout({ children, home, giveNavHeight }) {
      
          const pull_data = (data) => {
          const navHeight = data;
          giveNavHeight(navHeight);
        
          }
      return (
        <div className={styles.layoutWrap}>
        <Navbarmain func={pull_data}></Navbarmain>
```

**Lowest Child:**

```
export default function Navbarmain(props) {

  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    const navHeight = ref.current?.clientHeight;
    props.func(navHeight);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
```